# In Things Fall Apart by Chinua Achebe, why did Okonkwo not appeal to the Oracle on her decision to execute Ikemefuna?

Tags: chinua-achebe, things-fall-apart

In *Things Fall Apart*, was Okonkwo unable to appeal Ikemefuna's sentence due to religious customs, or was it a choice by the author to convey Okonkwo's unwillingness to be perceived as weak or unmanly?